# Document.getElementById().value returning Null in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, dom

I am getting null value from Lightning component from *document.getElementById().value* below is the case. I am showing already existed record as default(pricebookId) in the dropDown from total list.

```
<select class="selectPB" aura:id="selectPB" name="selectPB" style="margin-top:3%;margin-left:4%;" onchange="{!c.onSelectPB}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.pbs}" var="pb">
             <aura:if isTrue="{!pb.id==v.pricebookId}"> 
                <option selected="selected" value="{!pb.id}">{!pb.name}</option>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    <option value="{!pb.id}">{!pb.name}</option>
                </aura:set>
            </aura:if> 
        </aura:iteration>
    </select>
```

I need to get the value of *selectPB* from above mentioned piece of code. But it is returning NULL while using

> var selectedPBId = document.getElementById('selectPB').value;

But it is a bit strange. on the same page, I have another values which I am pulling. below is the code..

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
  <textarea id="notes" class="notes" value="{!v.notes}"/>
```

```
in controller/helper: var notes=document.getElementById("notes").value;
```

On the same dom, I am able to get notes value without any issues.
Why is this happening?? is there any workaround to get selectPB value from DOM?

Thanks a ton..

Comment: When you using aura:id in normal HTML tags use `component.find('selectPB').getElement().value` .When using `component.find('selectPB').getElement()` returns the DOM element for the  select Tag so then you can normally get it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your JS method to get the value it should work. do it in lightning way native way may break in future releases.

```
onSelectPB : function(component,event,helper){
    var selectedValue = component.find("selectPB"); 
    var optionValue = selectedValue.get("v.value"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the direct value using this. You need to do this.

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

You can also use Lightning:select for this. Then you can get direct value without using JS.

```
<lightning:select name="mySelect" label="Select a color:" aura:id="mySelect" value="{!v.selectedValue}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
         <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

and in the controller, you can simply get the variable `{!v.selectedValue}`